# @override method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, android

I'm having a small problem regarding my coding for android. I'm still very new to this and run into a small issue. No matter what I seem to do I cant seem to clear the error on my @override. The error is @override method does not override or implement a method from a supertype and the error is on all 3 of the last 3 @Override. Through that it comes up with an error for Menu, menu, MenuItem, itmsearch and KeyEvent saying cannot find symbol. Any help would be great and thank you in advance.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.setTitle("My Films");

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.film_list_cell,
    R.id.text,
    CELLS));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemsSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() ==R.id.itmsearch) {
    onSearchRequested();
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
        onSearchRequested();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



static final String[] CELLS = 
        new String[] {"Cell 0", "Cell 1", "Cell 2",
            "Cell 3", "Cell 4", "Cell 5",
            "Cell 6", "Cell 7", "Cell 8", 
            "Cell 9", "CEll 10"};
        }
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what error you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `onOptionsItemsSelected` to [onOptionsItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29).
................................................^

Here's the correct name of the method you want to override :

> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)

EDIT:

> Through that it comes up with an error for Menu, menu, MenuItem, itmsearch and KeyEvent saying cannot find symbol.

Make sure you import all the relevant classes :

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: Changed it but still leads to errors on the @Override

Comment: @Bcrscorpio The override for which of the 4 methods you are trying to override?

Comment: @Bcrscorpio Are you importing all the classes you are using? (for example - `import android.view.KeyEvent;`)

Comment: Yes!! Thats fixed the majority of it :D You sir are a god sent ! the only thing showing an error still is Menu is underlined as well as itmSearch, the error it gives me is cannot find symbol

Comment: Even after the import the error exists located in both the class R. Could it be down to a different error on a different script?